# Best way to drive high-output leds

Tags: microcontroller, led, pwm

In one project I need to drive high-output leds with a microcontroller. I am a beginner in electronics so I would need advice on how to do it...

There are 10 groups of 3 high-output leds. In each group the leds behave the same.
The microcontroller must be able to control for each group of leds :

- the switching frequency (on/off)
- the brightness with PWM

So it is like two imbricated PWM : one drive the power frequency, and the other the brightness of the leds.

How can I do that ? I have read about LED driver but I have never used them and I do not know what the best solution would be in such a configuration.

If you are familiar with this situation I am all ears. :)
Thanks

Comment: PWM means it is switching and that drives the brightness.  Generally all you need to do is use the PWM.  Now there may be other board components involved a resistor (ideally per led) and possibly a transistor plus some other components to support that.  Depends on how much current these leds need and how much each pin of your mcu and your mcu as a whole can deliver.

Comment: a 100% duty cycle basically means the output is always on. 0% always off 50% it is on half a clock period and off half the period.  the period you control as well as the duty cycle.  the led doesnt necessarily have a linear curve, so 50% isnt necessarily half brightness, but you can get the idea anyway. and tune as needed.  the period needs to be faster than the eye can detect but not so fast that the led doesnt respond to the pulses.  can be determined mathmatically no doubt but just try it.

Comment: start with a board with the leds already hooked up through resistors, the other end can be ground or vcc.  turning the pin on or high doesnt necessarily mean the led is on.  parts in the past and perhaps still can sink more than they can source, so not uncommon to find that turning the pin off, to zero, turns the led on.  doesnt matter start with simply turning the gpio pin on and off using normal gpio output high/low set/reset stuff.  see that you can make the led go on and stay on or stay off.

Comment: figure out how to program the pwm, ideally starting with a very slow time period that is in human visual range, so a second or half a second.  try a 50% duty cycle, so if the period is a second with a 50% duty cycle the led will be on for half a second and off for half a second.  then change the duty cycle to 75% try that, it should be on more than off (or off more than on depending on how it is wired up).  you are pretty much done then, shorten the period so it blinks faster than you can see, wrap this code with something to control the duty cycle of the pwm, muliply that by 10 groups.